# How to say something is "an acquired taste" in Chinese?

Tags: translation

A : "Do you like to eat Durian?"
B : "No not really"
A : "Yeah, I guess it's really an acquired taste"

Comment: For translation questions, please look around for an answer first; try sites such as iciba.com, google translate, and general web searches. If you can't find a good solution, you can come back here and edit your question to show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 4):

The English expression *acquired taste* refers to the nature of the taste being perhaps unpleasant on first taste, while one becomes habituated to like it through exposure, hence the *acquiring*. I would prefer a rendition such as:

> 可能需要慢慢地适应。
>
> 要慢慢来才会欣赏。

An idiom can be appropriate as a pithy reply:

> 一回生，二回熟。

Comment: +1 for the English explanation, but generally the idiom 一回生二回熟 is used to describe some circumstance, environment, or stranger, but not food, so it sounds figurative to my ears.

Comment: To supplement Stan's comment-- A typical use of 一回生、两回熟 is 学这件事要慢慢来；一回 __生__ ，两回**熟**。 lit. "To learn this thing, (you) need to learn it slowly; do it once (you're) __unskilled__; do it twice, (you're) **skilled**."

Answer (score 1):

how about 不吃不知道，一吃真奇妙 / 吃了忘不了 / 越吃越上瘾

Answer (score 0):

I find it is hard to translate it in a single cinese word. A few words for you to consider: （a taste you need to） 领略/领会/体会/体悟/尝试/熟悉/浸淫？

Answer (score -1):

the best answer is "青菜萝卜，各有所爱“